# Questions about Phantom Zone

Tags: dc

In the [DC Multiverse map](http://img2.timeinc.net/ew/i/2014/07/21/Multiversity-map_1400x1074.jpg) the Phantom Zone appears to be part of a **single** Underworld.

- Do all of Zod's soldiers go into the **same** Phantom Zone from each of the various multiverses? and if they do, do they go back to their **own universes** and to the same location in that universe from which they entered when they're released?

**and**

- Does this mean that Phantom Girl (and others who can enter the Phantom Zone) can use the Zone/Underworld as a simple method of transportation *between* different universes?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Despite their new map of the Multiverse, no regions on the DC Map of the Multiverse share any aspect of reality beyond a name in common. This is an intentional feature designed to allow writers to have alternative worlds to tell various stories without fear of corrupting the Prime Earth continuity.

- The realms that circle the Orrey of Worlds (the 52 separate realities) are all connected to the Orrey of Worlds and have their own unique versions of those realms.

> Orrery of Worlds: realm where the 52 universes exist in the same space, vibrating at different frequencies, within the Bleed. In the center of it are the Rock of Eternity and the House of Heroes. **[Wikipedia: Multiversity: New 52 entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse_(DC_Comics)#The_New_52_2)**

- Depending on the numbered realm, they may have a powerful connection to an outer realm or none at all. On Earth 2 for example, the connection to Apokalips was critical to the existence of Earth 2. Superman, Batman and Wonder Woman were killed by an incursion from Apokalips and this heralds a new generation of heroes there.

> - The Earth-2 concept has been revived as part of the publisher's The New 52 event, following another reboot of the DC Multiverse. The universe is covered in two series; Worlds' Finest, which focuses on the adventures of the Huntress and Power Girl on New Earth and which is currently (as of 2014) written by Paul Levitz, and Earth 2, written by Tom Taylor, which features the formation of the Justice Society.
> - James Robinson, the original writer of Earth 2, describes the new Earth 2 as a complete reboot of the concept, with superheroes only just now appearing, similar to the "young hero" concept for the New 52 continuity with revamped costume designs.

[image]

- In the DC Multiverse, each universe is a unique and separate realm separated by a vibrational frequency making each universe unique and access to their separate realms are limited to their individual universe. The boundary between parallel universes is known as [The Bleed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_(comics)).

> - The Bleed is not a universe in itself, but it is defined as the space between parallel universes. In the Wildstorm Universe, the most advanced beings can travel between parallel universes through the Bleed, or, simply, an arterial duct connecting to universes.
> - Travelling through the Bleed is not without danger though and sometimes objects or beings get lost, appearing in times and places they were never meant to go. In addition, the Bleed has mutagenic properties that alter the make-up of any sentient being that enters it directly. The effects can be beneficial or detrimental, depending on the circumstances of the exposure.

- It takes specialized equipment, technology and/or magic to be able to breach the dimensional boundaries between universes. Like the previous DC Universe, the ability to travel to other universe is difficult if not impossible without the correct tools.
- This includes all of the "outer zones" as well. Each number universe has its own versions of those outer realms unique to itself. The Phantom Zone of Earth 2 may resemble the Phantom Zone of Prime Earth, but they are not connected.
- The same vibrational differential that separates Earth Prime from Earth 2 also separates The Phantom Zone of Earth Prime from the Phantom Zone of Earth 2. Nor can anyone in the Phantom Zone of Earth Prime, cross over to the Phantom Zone of Earth 2.

**Each of these 52 universes is completely separate from any other.**